# Is there a limit to the number of applications I can submit to the app store?

Tags: iphone, app-store

Does anyone know if there is a limit to the number of applications I can submit to the app store?

I'd like to generate several applications (possibly climbing to 100 if it is wildly successful) all built from the same framework, but of interest to different groups.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, this guy submitted over 900 apps.  Of course, he ended up getting banned.  But, if your apps are useful and sufficiently different, I think you'll be fine.

http://www.mobilecrunch.com/2009/08/03/apple-bans-app-stores-3rd-most-prolific-developer/

Comment: That's helpful thanks. I'd only be submitting a lot if they were useful so I should be fine then.

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is no limit...

You might want to think about in-app purchases though...

Comment: I have considered in app purchases in depth, but one of my intentions is to brand each application to a specific organization and this would prevent this. It's a really good suggestion for others though - thanks for adding it.

Answer (score 2):

#### Not exactly.

There is no limit to the number that can be submitted, but since the process is entirely up to Apple and to individuals employed by Apple, the results are unpredictable.

Answer (score 2):

There is no limit on the number of apps you can submit and/or get approved but Apple is very sensitive to spammers so each app must provide unique value. You can't just have the same functionality under different names.

Here's the way to figure out if Apple will accept an app: Ask yourself if you, personally would be satisfied if you had spent time/money to download the app. If so, then Apple will probably approve the app because, as an app retailer, Apple is interested in making the customers happy and keeping them trusting in the app store.

In the case of multiple similar apps, ask yourself if you, personally, would be satisfied if you downloaded each and every version. In other words, would each app provide a unique value or would you find yourself feeling suckered for downloading the same basic functionality under different names?

From Apple's perspective, an app that doesn't provide value and functionality or that makes the customer feel exploited, damages the brand of the app store itself. Apple is ruthless in damaging its brand.

In designing apps, you should be focusing on providing value and functionality to the customer because that is why people buy software. Any other focus dooms a design because eventually people will stop using it if it doesn't do what it wants. Apple knows that and you should as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is no known limit to the number of apps you can have, but I would imagine that some people at Apple would frown on this. You might want to rethink your approach.